# xpages redirect to page and close current dialog

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

My button code :

```
    <xp:button value="Raport" id="button1" styleClass="lotusFormButton"
                            style="float:right;">
                            <xp:eventHandler event="onclick"
                                submit="true" refreshMode="complete" immediate="false"
                                save="true" id="eventHandler2">
                                <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.redirectToPage("export_hidden.xsp");
getcomponent('exampleDialog').hide()}]]></xp:this.action>
                            </xp:eventHandler>
                        </xp:button>
```

It just go to the `export_hidden.xsp` ( XAgent for creating an excel file ) but without closing the dialog.

I tried reverse the 2 actions, but same results.

I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a client-side call to `XSP.closeDialog('#{id:exampleDialog}')` in the onComplete event of the eventHandler.

Comment: Hello! I have the same context of the problem described, however even putting the command on the button's oncomplete the problem has not been solved. It only works if you do not pass the validation of the parameters that are required in the dialog. If you enter the parameters, excel is generated but the dialog is not closed.

Comment: Hello! I found a solution:
Replaces context.redirectToPage for view.postScript ("window.open ('" + myurl + "')")

That way it worked with the SSJS commands:

Var c = getComponent ("xxxx");
C.hide ();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to send an attachment to the user but remain on the same page. and after the attachment is delivered close the dialogbox.

the problem above is that your code tries to do two things at once. both clse the dialog and deliver the attachment. That isn't possible.

I see two solutions I would try.

1. Remove the getcomponent('exampleDialog').hide() and execute that thru a button onclick on a second hidden button in the oncomplete event.
2. If that don't work, set the url to the export_hidden.xsp in an hidden iframe in your dialogbox and also do a on button click on a hidden button the closes the dialogbox

Comment: Would a client-side call to XSP.closeDialog('#{id:exampleDialog}') in the onComplete event work?

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: it worked ! :-) Thank you! So, now should I accept Fredrik explanations? Or if you'll add an answer I'll mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Let me add an answer then :-)

Answer (score 0):

Doing the CSJS with partial update on the dialog box, along with context.redirectToPage(xAgentName) will work, Domino 9.0.1 FP9.